# Performance of classic sinatra and modular sinatra? am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

UPDATED:  OK, problem solved.

The different way I started the server makes the different result .

```
# this gives 2800 req/s in a production server, server based on thin
$ bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production    

# this gives 1600 req/s in the same server, server based on Rack( seems that)
$ bundle exec rackup config.ru -s thin
```

so the ways of starting sinatra:

1. wrong:  $ ruby main.rb (based on rack?)
2. wrong:  $ rackup config.ru (based on rack)
3. wrong:  $ rackup config.ru -s thin ( event based on rack)
4. correct: $ thin start -R config.ru -e production

-------------------  Original question --------------------

Today I am coding Sinatra for an API application, and found that:

1. Classic sinatra code can process :

   1.1 1800 request/s, with thin as the server.

   1.2 2000 request/s, with puma as the server.
2. Modular sinatra code can only process:

   2.1 1100 requests/s, with thin as the server

   2.2 800 requests/s , with puma as the server.

How to reproduce this:

## classic sinatra

```
# test_classic_sinatra.rb
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  'hihihi'
end
```

run :

```
siwei $ ruby test.rb 
== Sinatra (v2.0.5) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

test:

`$ ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost:4567/`

and got result:

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.530 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      211000 bytes
HTML transferred:       6000 bytes
Requests per second:    1885.43 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       53.038 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.530 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          388.50 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

## Modular sinatra:

```
# config.ru
require 'sinatra/base'

class App < Sinatra::Application
  set :environment, :production
  get '/' do
    'hihihi'
  end
end

run App
```

### with thin as server

run:

```
$ rackup config.ru -s thin
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

test:

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   0.931 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      211000 bytes
HTML transferred:       6000 bytes
Requests per second:    1073.58 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       93.146 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.931 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          221.22 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

### with puma as server

run:

```
siwei$ rackup config.ru 
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.11.4 (ruby 2.3.8-p459), codename: Love Song
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:9292
Use Ctrl-C to stop
```

test:

`$ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://localhost:9292/`

got result:

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   1.266 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Total transferred:      178000 bytes
HTML transferred:       6000 bytes
Requests per second:    789.62 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       126.643 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       1.266 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          137.26 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

Before deciding to use Sinatra, I read many posts about "sinatra, grape and rails api", and I ran test agaist these frameworks, and finally decide to use Sinatra.

But now , I found Modular Sinatra seems not so good as expected. Could someone give me a clue about how to use "Classic Sinatra" or "Modular Sinatra" ?

If I don't use Modular Sinatra, how to write code for big applications?

thanks a lot!

Comment: You run modular app in production env. And classic in what, development? Also, different servers are used, I think (thin vs puma?)

Comment: In other words, If you're going to compare fruits, compare apples to apples, not apples to oranges.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev on bare echo test everything under 10K is equally shitty btw :) here is a benchmark for 1M map value lookup response with `cowboy` + `plug` https://hexdocs.pm/camarero/camarero.html#benchmarks → 35K/sec approx.

Comment: Remove rackup from the equation. Without it, the two ways behave the same (on my machine)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: oh, I agree, if you want a fast lightweight service, ruby is not the best language. At least, MRI. Didn't try JVM's JIT magic, maybe it does work wonders.

Comment: "I don't trust theory, I trust the benchmarks" - you shouldn't, if you're doing them wrong, like here. Doing correct benchmarks (which includes, among other things, isolating _just_ the variable part and nothing else) is a skill of its own.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: hm, go's stock webserver does only 20k RPS on my machine. Guess erlang VM really is best for writing echo servers :)

Comment: Erlang VM is the best to write _any_ concurrent software btw.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin: except when you have a non-trivial workload and you need high performance, it seems. FWIW, erlang/elixir solutions failed _miserably_ at last year's [highloadcup](https://highloadcup.ru/en/). Reliability seems to be unquestionable, though, so there's that.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, the artificial task performed by people at contest proves the decades of success wrong. No doubt.

Comment: Please don't put "problem solved" information into your question. That's not the SO way. Instead, select the appropriate answer as the solution if there is one. If there's not the feel free to create an answer and select it as the solution once SO releases its timeout. FYI, SO is like an online encyclopedia of questions and answers, it's not like a message board. "[ask]" and the linked pages will help explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the root cause, and with The Tin Man's suggestion, I post my answer here.

The problem is the "web server" , but not the "framework"

The different way I started the server makes the different result .

```
# this gives 2800 req/s in a production server, server based on thin
$ bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production    

# this gives 1600 req/s in the same server, server based on Rack( seems that)
$ bundle exec rackup config.ru -s thin
so the ways of starting sinatra:
```

- wrong: $ ruby main.rb (based on rack?)
- wrong: $ rackup config.ru (based on rack)
- wrong: $ rackup config.ru -s thin ( event based on rack)
- correct: $ thin start -R config.ru -e production

Answer (score 2):

Your benchmark is incorrect.

According to the snippets you posted, in the first case you use Thin as a server and in the second it's Puma.

These servers implement absolutely different concurrency models: as far as I remember it is a single-threaded event loop for the former and multiple threads for the latter. As a result, Thin performs better for light non-blocking tasks while Puma beats it in the scenarios with relatively heavy computations or blocking ones.

Your dummy example just better fits to the Thin's model and this causes the difference... Modular Sinatra should be absolutely fine, just compare apples to apples :)

Comment: I don't think so. I just echo a very short fixed String, no database , no loop, and no thread waiting. the benchmark should not be so different.

Comment: I posted this question also to the sinatra github issues list. I totally agreed about your point on the "concurrency models between thin and puma". I just curious that it's OK if they are 20% performance difference, but should not almost 100% difference.

Comment: @SiweiShen申思维 now the figures are even more controversial... But I agree: looks like my naive "it's just because of the different servers used" is not a valid answer :)

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov: rackup is the culprit, looks like. :) Looks like a server issue from my end. So we weren't entirely off.